# Mounted My Tv and I missed one Stud(Top left corner of mount )

Tags: mounting

I for sure have 3 of my screws into the stud, but one of them missed the mark and I was wondering how much damage could it do. My Tv is about 35 pounds and was wondering how big of an issue is it because I didn't notice it until I move everything back.

Comment: Welcome!  A picture would be helpful, because many mounts are different.  It does sound like you should try to move the fourth screw into a stud.

Comment: You are probably fine but the size and type of screws will help to determine that.

Comment: Just leave the screw as is and add another that goes into the studs. Should be an easy fix